# XSD : How to set attributes values in children element type?

Tags: c++, xsd, xsd.exe, codesynthesis

In an xsd file I have this element base type :

```
<xs:complexType name="event" abstract="true" >
    <xs:attribute name="move" type="aos:move_ref" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="aos:event_type" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

And I want to define the value of the `type` attribute in the children types, so I tried this :

```
<xs:complexType name="signal" >
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="aos:event">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="aos:event_type" fixed="signal" />
        <xs:attribute name="source" type="aos:signal_source" use="required" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
```

Visual Studio don't seem to bother but [CodeSynthesis C++ code generator](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd) don't seem to agree :

> error: attribute 'type' is already
>   defined in base

How should I write this? I just want the value of the `type` attribute to be specific to each different child type.

edit ----

To make the question more clear, I'll write the same thing I want to do but in C++.

Here is the base class :

```
class Event
{
public:

   std::string name() const { return m_name; }

protected:

   // we need the child class to set the name
   Event( const std::string& name ) : m_name( name ) {} 

   // it's a base class
   virtual ~Event(){}

private:

   std::string m_name;

};
```

Now, one of the children could be implemented like this :

```
class Signal : public Event
{
public:

   Signal() : Event( "signal" ){}

};
```

As you can see, the child class define the values of attributes that are defined by the base class. Is it even possible to express in xsd?

Comment: can you get us a sample XML please ?

Comment: Is it really necessary? I can but I don't see how it can help. You want some kind of use-case?

Comment: nope, I just want to be clarified, not clear with ur statement like `I just want the value of the type attribute to be specific to each different child type`, if you want to define an attribute **differently** under same child/entity then its not possible, where as if you want to define same attribute differently for different entity/children then quite possible.

Comment: I want the same attribute to have different values defined by the child types. If there is really no way to set a value to an attribute that was defined in the base type can't be set in the child type, then please make it an answer?

Comment: In fact, in the xml, this will not be apparent. It will only be apparent if you try to get the "type" attribute from different element types, here <signal> for example. Maybe that's not useful in the end, I'm asking myself if I can have the information another way.

Comment: I added a C++ version of what I want to achieve, hoping it makes the question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive a type and fix a value, use a [restriction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DerivByRestrict):

```
<xs:complexType name="signal" >
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="aos:event">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="aos:event_type" fixed="signal" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="source" type="aos:signal_source" use="required" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
```

From reading the spec, I would have expected that you [couldn't add attributes in a restriction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#c-rad) unless the base type had an [attribute wildcard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#ct-attribute_wildcard), but the W3C XSD validator accepts the above. If you run into problems, you can break up the definition into a restriction and an extension:

```
<xs:complexType name="fixedSignalEvent">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:restriction base="aos:event">
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="aos:event_type" fixed="signal" use="required" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="signal" >
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="aos:fixedSignalEvent">
      <xs:attribute name="source" type="aos:signal_source" use="required" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Another fix would be to add an [attribute wildcard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#element-anyAttribute) to the base type.

```
<xs:complexType name="event" abstract="true" >
    <xs:attribute name="move" type="aos:move_ref" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="aos:event_type" use="required" />
    <xs:anyAttribute />
</xs:complexType>
```

This isn't an equivalent solution, as it allows an event to have anything for an attribute (which may be undesirable, generally speaking, but perhaps not for code generation), and it doesn't add an additional type (which is desirable).

Note that any particles (elements, groups or wildcards) in the base must be [repeated in the restriction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DerivByRestrict), else they won't be allowed in the element. If a restricted attribute is required on the base, it must also be required in the restriction. There are numerous other properties a restriction must fulfill to be a valid [derivation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#derivation-ok-restriction) or [particle](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-particle-restrict). The spec isn't that readable, but you can usually stumble through it.

See also: "[how to use restrictions and extensions in XSD simultanously](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/604681-how-use-restrictions-extensions-xsd-simultanously)".

Comment: It seems that this parser still don't like the fact that I'm repeating the declaration of the attribute even using restriction over extension (with a simple child type that only tries to set the value of this attribute) ... too bad :/

Comment: Wait, I did a mistake, it seems to works! I wasn't trying to parse the right file, sorry! I'll have to do more checks and do the trick for more complex children class.

Comment: Ok so with complex children (that extend the type) I can't find how to "break up the definition into a restriction and an extension". Can I do this in the same complex type? Can you add an example?

Comment: Does the additional example clarify things? Note you can't nest restrictions within extensions (or vice versa), so you'll need two separate complex types.

Comment: Yes that's clear. That's what I guessed but hoped their was a more intuitive way. The separation is their only to set values, that's not good design... but if it's the only way then I'll do this. Thanks!

Comment: XSD is rather unique in distinguishing restriction from extension. In C++ (as other OO languages), all that's important is that deriving a type through inheritance produces one that's [more specific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science) than the base. This difference isn't too surprising, considering that the languages apply to different domains.

Comment: It seems that Visual Studio don't agree that the final type has his property set in it's parent type :/ 
I'll try to generate code see what it says.

Comment: I generated the code but it don't generate the corresponding code. In fact I'm thinking I'm doing it the bad way maybe. I just can't find an alternative to keep the common interface.

Comment: Check updated answer. You may find using an attribute wildcard is preferable to two separate classes.

Comment: Sorry, in fact this solution work but the generated code wasn't what I expected and it didn't work as I thought. In fact the "required" attribute of attributes makes it all wrong as it make all child types require the attribute too even if you define a value in the restriction. Other than that I didn't see that the restriction set the value in the generated C++ code only if you provide the xsd for validation. So your solution was good, thank you very much :) I got confirmation on the mailing list of the generator tool.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't any way of removing "required" that I know of. If `event` is supposed to be an ABC, you could simply remove the "required" from the `type` attribute of `event`.